# Как слить изменения из одной ветки в другую?

Tags: git

Есть пулл реквесты, на каждый пул по веточке.
В пулл реквесте, например `Task_3`, нужно провести рефакторинг, и применить все изменения к `Task_4`, т.е. к ветке, производную от предыдущей.

Как лучше это сделать?

Comment: Ничего непонятно, но наверное вам нужен git merge

Comment: Я что-то сделала в одной ветке. С этой ветки сделала еще одну ветку - дальше что-то разрабатывать. В предыдущей необходимо провести рефакторинг, изменения как-то "скопировать", чтобы при мерже со следующей было без конфликтов, и чтобы дальнейшая разработка была с теми изменениями, что были внесены при рефакторинге. Как-то так

Comment: Так у вас проблемы с процессом. Рассмотрите возможности `git rebase` и разберитесь в разнице между *публичными репозиториями* и *опубликованными ветками*. Тогда работа с `git rebase` станет намного понятнее и удобнее.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется я разобралась. Достаточно было сделать git pull origin Task3 находясь на task4 ветке ну и порешать конфликты потом